# Virus detection in http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nmap/nmap-common_7.70%2bdfsg1-6_all.deb

Tags: updates

do you know something about this,
when we try to update one KUbuntu machine updates file was blocked by our firewall.
File:       http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nmap/nmap-common_7.70%2bdfsg1-6_all.deb

Protocol:       HTTP 
Virus info:         Kerio Antivirus verdict: VIRUS: Gen:Variant.Ursu.416173

We try to download it from the different server but we got the same alert.
is there any known problem with the updates?

Answer (score 4):

`Gen:Variant.Ursu.416173` is a Windows related problem.  Besides that: you can expect the official mirrors to be scanned anyway.

> Nmap (Network Mapper) is a free and open-source network scanner and is used to discover hosts and services on a computer network by sending packets and analyzing the responses.

So basically it does exactly what those virus scanners believe is a virus: scan ports. But that is what it is *supposed* to do.

> is there any known problem with the updates?

No. Get a better virus scanner, please. Or better: don't use virus scanners on Linux files. The only logical usage for virus scanners on Linux is to scan Windows files before you send them to a Windows system.

As of today, there are [26 known viruses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware#Viruses) related to Linux; None of these are current and this also includes proof of concepts. [Some of them are described here](https://www.unixmen.com/meet-linux-viruses/).

An Intrusion Detection Prevention System is far more important

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But we never had any issues before with updating our Linux machines and about this, I asked. That file how I said was blocked by the Kerio network firewall and wasn't scanned by the antivirus in the machine.

Comment: Also when I download the latest ISO there is no problem with the firewall.

Comment: Tell the people from kerio they messed up their definitions